# Optional paths within single $routeProvider rule

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

Is it possible to write a rule such as this:

```
$routeProvider.when('(/CostMin/:costMin)?(/CostMax/:costMax)?(/Keywords/:keywords)?', {
    ...
});
```

Which matches each path contained in parenthesis *optionally*? So the above rule would match all of the following paths:

```
/
/CostMin/0
/CostMin/0/CostMax/10
/CostMin/0/CostMax/10/Keywords/rope
/Keywords/rope

// And so on...
```

Comment: I don't believe you can use regular expressions in the path. The question is, why would you want to do this?

Comment: @link64 I'm really not sure that is the question. Why wouldn't I want a neat route with only required parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's possible to specify routes in this way, but usually for this kind of route you'd just use search params, like `/?q=rope&costMin=0&costMax=10` (I'm assuming this is a search operation). This way, the params are optional and it will still match the base path.

Just specify the route like this:

```
$routeProvider.when('/', { ... });
```

and then inject `$routeParams` into your controller and you can access the params:

```
$routeParams = { q: 'rope', costMin: '0', costMax: '10' }
```